# Number theory olympiad problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, integers, divisor-sum

This is a problem I have been tackling recently, but I am unsure how to address it.

**A positive integer $n$ is *good* if there exists a set of divisors of $n$ whose members sum to $n$ and include $1$. Prove that every positive integer has a multiple which is *good*.**

Any help with a solution appreciated.

Comment: Ongoing contest ?

Comment: You are misreading the assertion: "Prove that every positive integer has a multiple which is good. ... multiples of 6 work only up to 60 since 66 is not good".  The assertion is saying that there is **at least one** multiple of 6 that is good, **not** that all multiples of 6 are good.

Comment: @user2661923 I think they know this. Note that they haven't claimed that the problem must be wrong because $6\cdot 11$ fails to be good. I suspect they're just hoping "Given $n$, let's try $6n$ and see how often that's good." At least that's my take.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try for multiples of the form $2^pn$ where $n$ is odd and $p$ is large.

Full solution:

> Let $n$ be an odd integer; there are $a_1 > a_2 > \ldots > a_k=0$ such that $n=\sum_{l=1}^k{2^{a_l}}$. Let $p \geq a_1$, then $2^pn=(2^p-1)n+n=\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}{2^ln}+\sum_{l=1}^k{2^{a_l}}$ so $n2^p$ is good.

> Let $A$ be any integer, then $A|B$ for some integer $B$ of the form $2^ab$ where $a \geq 1$, $b \geq 3$ is odd. We know that for large enough $p$, $2^pb$ is good. But for such large enough $p$, $2^ab|2^pb$ so $A|2^pb$ and $2^pb$ is good.